# Combining two FOR commands (/f /l) in a batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, dos

Okay guys, I am fairly new to working with batch files and I have two files I have previously created which are both working independantly.

I am looking to combine them but I still do not fully understand the FOR command. I was hoping someone could combine these two sets of code into one and if possible explain how the came up with the code they used from my two sources.

1. This file copies another file (in this case test.txt) to every subdirectory in a directory

`FOR /R d:\ %%A IN (test.txt) DO copy d:\%username%\Desktop\Test\Resources\test.txt %%A

 FOR /R h:\ %%A IN (test.txt) DO copy d:\%username%\Desktop\Test\Resources\test.txt %%A`

1. This file copies and renames another file X amount of times (in this case 5) renaming each succesive copy in increments of 1.

`For /l %%1 in (1,1,10) do (
    copy test.txt test%%1.txt > nul
)`

Basically I want the selected file (test.txt) to be copied from a set location to every subdirectory within a directory and then copied in each folder X amount of times and renamed with increasing values e.g.

test1.txt

test2.txt

test3.txt

etc.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually very straight forward.

You already have functioning code that copies from the source to each subdirectory. In pseudo code: `FOR (each directory) DO COPY source to target`.

You also have code that can copy the file 10 times with incrementing names. You want to do this for each directory in the 1st step. So, again in pseudo code, it will look something like this:

```
FOR (each directory) DO (
  COPY source to target
  FOR (N=1 TO 10) DO COPY source to targetN
)
```

None of the syntax above is real, except that the parentheses after the DO are actually how you allow a batch FOR command to execute a block of multiple commands. (Actually there are other techniques to do this, but the parens work just fine.)

The part that you are missing is how to insert the incrementing number into the %%A target name. This is done by using FOR variable modifiers, as described at the end of the FOR documentation that you can access from the command line by typing `HELP FOR`, or `FOR /?`.

The modifiers allow you to deconstruct a file specification into its component parts. Note that the file doesn't have to physically exist, the file spec can still be broken down into the constituent parts.

- `%%~dpnA` = drive:\path\baseName  (no extension)
- `%%~xA` = .extension, including the dot.

You've already got the incrementing number - I'm going to use `%%N` instead of `%%1`. So the full target will be the concatenation of the 3 components: `%%~dpnA%%N%%~xA`.

Putting it all together gives the full solution:

```
FOR /R d:\ %%A IN (test.txt) DO (
  copy d:\%username%\Desktop\Test\Resources\test.txt %%A
  FOR /L %%N IN (1 1 10) DO copy d:\%username%\Desktop\Test\Resources\test.txt %%~dpnA%%N%%~xA
)
```